# merge 3 dataframes into a matrix

Tags: pandas

i have 3 dataframes.

1. warehouse_to_outlet_distance.

   ```
   wh_name   outlet_id    distance
   aaa        111            10
   aaa        222            20
   aaa        333            30
   ```
2. outlet_to_outlet_distance

   ```
   source_outlet_id   dest_outlet_id    distance
   111                    222           5
   111                    333           7
   222                    111           8
   222                    333           6
   333                    111          10
   333                    222          12
   ```
3. outlet_to_warehouse_distance

   ```
   outlet_id   wh_name  dist
   111         aaa      13
   222         aaa      15
   333         aaa      11
   ```

i want to convert this into a martix:

```
       0    111      222       333
  0    0     10       20        30       
111   13      0        5         7
222   15      8        0         6
333   11     10       12         0
```

where 0 representd 'warehouse'
in row 1 , the distance between warehouse(0) to outlet 111 is **10**, which is put in the respective cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshape and then add new row and new column, last sort index and columns names:

```
df = outlet_to_outlet_distance.set_index(['source_outlet_id','dest_outlet_id'])['distance']
                              .unstack(fill_value=0)
df[0] = outlet_to_warehouse_distance.set_index('outlet_id')['dist']
#appended 0 Series for avoid NaN in 0,0
df.loc[0] = warehouse_to_outlet_distance.set_index('outlet_id')['distance']
                                        .append(pd.Series(0, index=[0]))
df = df.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
df = df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)
print (df)
     0    111  222  333
0      0   10   20   30
111   13    0    5    7
222   15    8    0    6
333   11   10   12    0
```

Alternative:

```
df = outlet_to_outlet_distance.pivot('source_outlet_id','dest_outlet_id', 'distance')
df[0] = outlet_to_warehouse_distance.set_index('outlet_id')['dist']
df.loc[0] = warehouse_to_outlet_distance.set_index('outlet_id')['distance']
df = df.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
df = df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)
print (df)
     0    111  222  333
0      0   10   20   30
111   13    0    5    7
222   15    8    0    6
333   11   10   12    0
```